# mongodb slow simple queries in production environment

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-mms

All queries are taking too much time to complete in a web server database.

Asking for simple documents in a big indexed collection in another machine takes <0ms, in the production machine takes ~20ms-300ms.

The hardware is the next:

```
PowerEdge R410 with a X5660
2 TB SATA disks
16 GB ram
```

In a machine with a E3-1230v2 and 250gb SSD disk and 24gb ram works fine.

Before upgrading the machine or changing it for another one (ssd+64gb ram+E3-1270v3), I have to find the bottleneck.

1. I'm suspecting of **memory mapped**, the **page faults** values are high.
2. I don't know why mapped memory is **280 gb** and db storage only **46 gb**.
3. **php-fpm** processes reaches 100% of the cpu, if the queries are slow and the php is waiting for a response, it consumes cpu?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried enabling profiling to ensure that it's actually the query that's taking too long?  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Comment: @Mason: Yes, I have profiled all queries, any query is slower than in local and other machines. It's probably a memory issue.

Comment: Hmm your gonna find way more help on DBA frankly